# Display Wechat Moment (timeline) in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, timeline, wechat

Is it possible to display Moment (timeline) from WeChat in UIWebView or any other way to retrieve the timeline contents so I can display it in my app?

I need to display the timeline of an official account from WeChat in my app just like how we display a Facebook page in app through UIWebView. I had tried WeChat API but it only allows sharing contents to WeChat app.

Previously I tried directing my app to launch WeChat app for sharing/publishing contents, but Apple had rejected it and the reason is user needs to install other app in order to use our app feature.

Thanks so much for your time =]